# Return multiple results from SQL Server

Tags: c#, return-value, blazor-server-side

Currently I can input a product name into a textbox and search that name in the SQL Server database. And return ONLY a single unique row. This works fine. But when I search for e.g. Bike. I need Blue bike AND Red Bike to be returned.

I currently have:

```cs
public List<Product> GetProductByName(string name)
{
    List <Product> productList = new List<Product>();
    using (var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        productList.Add(context.Product.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProductName == name));
        return productList;
    }
}
```

Currently I'm getting a System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains more than one element'.

Comment: To fix the exception and return multiple products with the same name, you can use the Where method instead of SingleOrDefault.

Comment: Great that works. How would I apply a search if I want to return a product whose name is close to the searched name. e.g. searching for car returns motorCAR as it contains the keyword?

Comment: " searching for car returns motorCAR as it contains the keyword?" you won't believe how intuitive the linq methods are named: [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-7.0) this will be translated into `LIKE %MySearchWord%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `SingleOrDefault` if you're expecting multiple rows. Perhaps instead:

```cs
using (var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    return context.Product.Where(x => x.ProductName == name).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use Contains in Where:

```
using (var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
 {
    return context.Product.Where(x => x.ProductName.Contains(name)).ToList();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Product> GetProductByName(string name)
{
    List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
    using (var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        productList = context.Product.Where(x => x.ProductName == name).ToList();
        return productList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this unnecessarily creates 2 separate lists

Comment: You can avoid creating two separate lists by directly returning the result of the Where method.
however, this is the best way to learn for coders who are just beginning their journey.

Comment: "this is the best way to learn for coders who are just beginning their journey" really? to instantiate a list outside of the using block for no apparent reason? I don't see any advantage in the learning process due to that fact